# When would an 'is' predicate ever be needed, as opposed to using the 'in' operator?

Tags: typescript

[According to the TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) we can use TypeGuards to differentiate between types.

The documentation gives examples using the `is` predicate, and using the `in` operator.

**`is` predicate:**

```
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
    return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}

if (isFish(pet)) {
    pet.swim();
}
else {
    pet.fly();
}
```

**`in` operator:**

```
function move(pet: Fish | Bird) {
    if ("swim" in pet) {
        return pet.swim();
    }
    return pet.fly();
}
```

The `in` operator seems a lot more concise and simpler - although perhaps explicitly pulling the type differentiation into a function is helpful and easier to maintain in the long run.

Are there any cases where the `is` predicate can differentiate between types where the `in` operator cannot?

Comment: This seems reasonable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `in` operator is just one way of narrowing the type of a variable. You can write type guards using any checks you like:

```js
type JSONPrimitive = number | string | boolean | null;

function isJsonPrimitive(x: any): x is JSONPrimitive {
    return x === null
        || typeof x === 'number'
        || typeof x === 'string'
        || typeof x === 'boolean';
}
```

Or:

```
interface TreeNode {
    value: number;
    left: TreeNode | null;
    right: TreeNode | null;
}
type InternalNode = TreeNode & ({ left: TreeNode } | { right: TreeNode });

function isInternalNode(node: TreeNode): node is InternalNode {
    return node.left !== null || node.right !== null;
}
```

Neither of these examples can be rewritten equivalently using the `in` operator.

That said, user-defined type guards are similar to [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), in that Typescript does not check their correctness. So you can use literally any logic you like in the implementation of your type guard; even an unconditional `return true;` is allowed.